# how to pass variable from jquery to php in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to pass jquery variable to other php page in php code. but i can't. so Please help me.

```
    <div class="span4" style="padding-top: 4px;">                    
     <h3><a name="works" id="w"> <?php echo $filename; ?></a></h3>
      </div>
<input name="filename" type="hidden"   id="filename"/>
function formtext() {

                 var aa = $('#w').text();
                alert(aa);
                $.ajax({
                    url   : "exporttodoc.php",
                    type  : "POST",
                    cache : false,
                    data  : {
                        aa : aa
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: are getting any errors?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: aa in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\assets\src\exporttodoc.php on line 5

Comment: What exactly is your error? Have you checked your PHP script that's accepting `$_POST['aa']`?

Comment: If a variable is `undefined` $.ajax will NOT send it over. Make sure you select it properly.

Comment: actually the aa may be not passed.. So what can i do?

Comment: `var aa = '' + $(#w).text();`?

Comment: Could you give you file structure so we can help you ? I think the problem is also in the url

Answer (score 1):

You can do this and it will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formtext() {

                $.ajax({
                    url   : "exporttodoc.php",
                    type  : "POST",
                    cache : false,
                    data  : {
                        aa : '<?php echo $filename; ?>'
                    }
                });
}
</script>
```

In the other file you just go get it like so

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST['aa'];

...
```

But your method seems to work fine, I think, but you need to include the script tags before and after function formtext, just see my example

**EDIT:** You need to call the function formtext() so it can do the ajax post

Comment: You can't assign file name like this, need to add quotation '<?php echo $filename; ?>'

Comment: but i want to pass the value of id#w. because it is content editable

Comment: i also call this function and the tag. but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <div class="span4" style="padding-top: 4px;">                    
     <h3><a name="works" id="w">  <?php echo $filename; ?></a></h3>
      </div>
<input name="filename" type="hidden"   id="filename"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function formtext() {
                 var aa = $('#w').text();
                alert(aa);
                $.ajax({
                    url   : "exporttodoc.php",
                    type  : "POST",
                    cache : false,
                    data  : {
                        'aa' : aa
                    }
                });
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formtext() 
{

                var aa = $('#w').text();
                alert(aa);
                $.ajax({
                    url   : "exporttodoc.php",
                    type  : "POST",
                    cache : false,
                    data  : {
                        aa : aa
                    }
                });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a script tag, and it might have been better to include your PHP code as well.

Here is an example of what you might do:

HTML File:

```
<a href="#" id="w" onclick="return formtext();"><?php echo $filename; ?></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready() {
function formtext() {
    var aa = $('#w').text();
    alert(aa);
    $.ajax({
        url   : "exporttodoc.php",
        type  : "POST",
        cache : false,
        data  : {
            aa : aa
        }
    });
}
}

</script>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php

// Use the data like this:
$_POST['aa'];

?>
```